# method not supported error occurs while running hive query or fetching tables from hive on pentaho tool

Tags: hadoop, hive, pentaho-data-integration

I have used pentaho 6.1,hive 2.1.0,hadoop 2.7.3
The connection to hive2 from pentaho is successful on port 10001,
after clicking browse.. to get list of tables from hive database 
the following error occurs

```
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Unable to retrieve database information because of an error

Unable to get list of procedures from database meta-data: 

Unable to get list of rows from ResultSet : 

Error determining value metadata from SQL resultset metadata
Method not supported
```

i copied all hive-*.jar from apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/lib to \pdi-ce-6.1.0.1-196\data-integration\lib